# Not prompted to authorize Visual Studio with the GitHub Copilot service

Tags: visual-studio, github-copilot

I have just installed `Github Copilot` in my Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Preview 1.0

[image]

But when I re-open Visual Studio, I am not prompted to authorize Visual Studio with the GitHub Copilot service.

It this due to my Visual Studio Preview version?

Comment: After waiting for 30 minutes, I can get the prompt to authorize Visual Studio with the GitHub Copilot service.